# Display the ORIGINAL text of a paragraph with a Tracked Change without rejecting the change

Tags: vba, ms-word, revision

I am trying to write a Macro that can display the Original proposed text in a tracked change without having to reject the change.

Worked out the below code from another post ([Display the final proposed text in Tracked Change without accepting the change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62551674/display-the-final-proposed-text-in-tracked-change-without-accepting-the-change)) on how to see the final proposed text without accepting the change:

```
With oRevision
    With ActiveWindow.View
        'Capturing final paragraph text after revision
        .ShowRevisionsAndComments = False
        .RevisionsView = wdRevisionsViewFinal
        strText = oRevision.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
        'Reverting document back to the normal view and capturing original paragraph text
        .ShowRevisionsAndComments = True
        .RevisionsView = wdRevisionsViewOriginal
        strTextORIGINAL = oRevision.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
    End With
End With
```

Now I need to do the opposite, in the variable **strTextORIGINAL**, I would like to capture the original text before the revision was proposed and without rejecting the change. Currently whenever I check **oRevision.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text** it is showing both the original text together with the new text proposed in the revision, how do I get only the original text?

Comment: If you save a copy of the document you're free to perform any "irreversible" actions on the copy without affecting the original.

Comment: There are 100s of revisions which I'm looping through, therefore need to keep updating the revision view and reset again for each loop

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you need to use:

```
.ShowRevisionsAndComments = False
```

Comment: It works, but sometimes just an empty string is returned, the vba is not able to pick up the original paragraph text for random revisions, just returns empty string, other times it works fine

Comment: Well, if it's a new paragraph, that's exactly what one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do fancy coding and came up with the below that gets the job done. Basically have to loop through all the revisions and check against previous revisions info to make sure paragraphs for which multiple changes were made do not get repeated in the output. This even takes care of the issue of the output being blank sometimes, since we are consolidating all the revisions in each paragraph together.

Anyone can feel free to use this :)

```
For Each oRevision In oDoc.Revisions
   Select Case oRevision.Type
        'Only include insertions and deletions
        Case wdRevisionInsert, wdRevisionDelete
            With oRevision
                With ActiveWindow.View
                    'Capturing final paragraph text after revision
                    .ShowRevisionsAndComments = False
                    .RevisionsView = wdRevisionsViewFinal
                    strTextFINAL = oRevision.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
                    'Capturing original paragraph text
                    .RevisionsView = wdRevisionsViewOriginal
                    strTextORIGINAL = oRevision.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
                    'Reverting document back to the normal view
                    .ShowRevisionsAndComments = True
                End With
            End With
                    
            'Incrementing row if no duplication of statement
            If oRevision.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = ParagraphPrevious Then
                index = index - 1
            Else 'Resetting duplicate check values
                strTextORIGINALPrevious = ""
                strTextFINALPrevious = ""
            End If
            ParagraphPrevious = oRevision.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text 'Storing value for re-use in next loop
            index = index + 1
                
            'START OF DATA CHECKING WITH CORRECTIONS
            If oRevision.Type = wdRevisionInsert And strTextORIGINALPrevious = "" Then
                strTextORIGINAL = Replace(strTextFINAL, oRevision.Range.Text, "")
            ElseIf oRevision.Type = wdRevisionInsert And strTextORIGINALPrevious <> "" Then
                strTextORIGINAL = Replace(strTextORIGINALPrevious, oRevision.Range.Text, "")
            End If
            strTextORIGINALPrevious = strTextORIGINAL 'Storing value for re-use in next loop
               
            If oRevision.Type = wdRevisionDelete And strTextFINALPrevious = "" Then
                strTextFINAL = Replace(strTextORIGINAL, oRevision.Range.Text, "")
            ElseIf oRevision.Type = wdRevisionDelete And strTextFINALPrevious <> "" Then
                strTextFINAL = Replace(strTextFINALPrevious, oRevision.Range.Text, "")
            End If
            strTextFINALPrevious = strTextFINAL 'Storing value for re-use in next loop
                
            If Len(strTextFINAL) <= 1 And oRevision.Type = wdRevisionDelete Then 'When paragraph has been fully deleted
                strTextFINAL = "ENTIRELY DELETED"
            End If
            'END OF DATA CHECKING WITH CORRECTIONS
            
            'Insert data in cells in row
            'The document name
            .Cells(index, 1) = oDoc.FullName
            'Page number
            .Cells(index, 2) = oRevision.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
            'Line number - start of revision
            .Cells(index, 3) = oRevision.Range.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
            'Original paragraph
            .Cells(index, 4) = strTextORIGINAL
            'Final paragraph with proposed changes
            .Cells(index, 5) = strTextFINAL
    End Select
Next oRevision
```